# About thrust::execution_policy when copying data from device to host

Tags: c++, cuda, benchmarking, gpgpu, thrust

I use `thrust::copy` to transfer data from **device to host** in a multi-GPU system. Each GPU has a equally sized partition of the data. Using OpenMP, I call the function on each device. On my current system I am working on 4 GPUs.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < devices.size(); ++i) 
{
    const int device = devices[i];
    thrust::copy(thrust::device, // execution policy
                 device_buffers->At(device)->begin(), // thrust::device_vector
                 device_buffers->At(device)->end(),
                 elements->begin() + (device * block_size)); // thrust::host_vector
}
```

After reading the documentation and the following [post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/default-thrust-execution-policy/50896), I understand that the default thrust::execution_policy is chosen based on the iterators that are passed.

- When copying data from device to host, both iterators are passed as
  function parameters.

  **1. Which execution policy is picked here per default?** `thrust::host` or `thrust::device`?
- After doing some benchmarks, I observe that passing thrust::device
  explicitly improves performance, compared to not passing an explicit
  parameter.
  **2. What could be the reason for the performance gain?** The system is a [POWER9](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp5472.pdf) machine. How does thrust::copy and the specific execution
  policy work internally? **How many of the 4 copy engines of each
  device are actually used?**
- However, nvprof does not display the [CUDA memcpy DtoH] category
  anymore and instead shows void thrust::cuda_cub::core [...]
  __parallel_for::ParallelForAgent [...] which even shows an increase in Time (s). This does not make sense because, as I said, I observed
  a consistent performance improvement (smaller total execution time)
  when using thrust::device.

  **3. Is this just a nvprof + thrust-specific behaviour that causes profiling numbers not to correlate with acutal execution time?**  I
  observed something similiar for cudaFree: It seems that cudaFree is
  returning control to the host code pretty fast which results in small
  execution time while nvprof shows much higher numbers because the
  actual deallocation probably happens in lazy fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thrust [doc](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__execution__policies_ga78249cb3aa4239b64e65aaf6e82ac2f8.html#ga78249cb3aa4239b64e65aaf6e82ac2f8) on the `thrust::device` states the following:

> Raw pointers allocated by host APIs should not be mixed with a thrust::device algorithm invocation when the device backend is CUDA

To my understanding, this means that host-device copy with `thrust::device` execution policy is invalid, in the first place, unless the host memory is pinned.

We imply that your host allocation is not pinned, **BUT:** One possibility is that on POWER9 with NVLINK you may be lucky that any host-allocated memory is addressable from within the GPU. Thanks to that, host-device copy with `thrust::device` works, though it should not.

On a regular system, host memory is addressable from within a GPU only if this host memory is allocated with `cudaMallocHost` (pinned). So, the question is **whether your POWER system has automagically upgraded all allocations to be pinned. Is the observed performance bonus due to the implicitly-pinned memory, or would you get an additional speedup, if allocations are also done with `cudaMallocHost` explicitly?**

Another Thrust design-based evidence is that `thrust::device` policy has `par.on(stream)` support, while `thrust::host` does not. This is pretty much aligned with the fact that asynchronous host-device copies are only possible with the pinned memory.

Comment: power9 has a [ATS feature](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-system-allocator) that allows host allocated pointers (whether pinned or not) to be dereferenceable either from host or device code, however there may be negative performance implications